# How to Include additional field in Rails 3 Application JSON Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a Rails application which displays nested form in json format.

In the JSON Response i am also displaying an id field which represent another table.

How to display name corresponding to that id what i am getting so that i can display both name and id in my json format.

My controller
show method

```
def show
    @maintemplate = Maintemplate.find(params[:id])
    respond_with (@maintemplate) do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @maintemplate }
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but how about `render :json => @maintemplate.to_json`?

Comment: i am getting the Json format quite well,problem is ,in my json format i am displaying an id field(eg:  "user_id" : "12" ),which corresponds to User table. I want to include the name corresponding to this id("12") in my json format.How to fix this.

Comment: Ok posted an answer, see below.

Comment: i dont want to change the name in json format,i want to fetch the name corresponding to this id(say id=12) from my user table ,so that i can display both id and name in my json format.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The code below returns a JSON where `["user"]["name"]` is the name of the user with `user_id = 12`. That user id will also be in the JSON. I've updated my example below to make this clear (but the code is the same).

Comment: Also: the "fetch" happens when you use the `:include` option in `to_json`. That tells rails to include the associated record when it fetches `@maintemplate` from the DB.

Comment: Correction: the `:include` option tells rails to fetch the associated record before converting to JSON format.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
render :json => @maintemplate.to_json(:include => { :user => { :only => :name } } )
```

This will replace the `user_id` key with a `user` key and a value with only the `name` attribute of `user`, like this:

```
{
  "user_id": "12"
  "user": { "name": "..." }
  ...
}
```

You can then access the username in the json response with `["user"]["name"]`. You can also access the user id with `["user_id"]`.

For more see the [documentation on `as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json).

**Update:**

Using the info provided in the comments, I think this is what you actually want:

```
render :json => @maintemplate.to_json(:include => { :routine => { :include => :user, :user => { :only => :name } } } )
```

Comment: my "@maintemplte" is a nested form output .it has array of template1 inside "@maintemplate" , template1 is having array of template2....my user_id is lying inside each template2.

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly? What do you mean `@maintempalte` is a nested form output? It's the result of a `find` method call, so it should be a model instance.

Comment: "@maintemplate" is a model instance.It containd "days" array.Days array is having "routine" array.All these are comming from different model (days, routine, maintemplate)."maintemplate" model id having day_id and routine_id.Routine model is having user_id (ie displaying  in json format as output with many other field).This user_id corresponds to user table which is having name ,age etc.... I want to include this name also in this json output corresponds to what user_id i am getting.

Comment: Can you clarify: does your `Maintemplate` model `has_many :routines`, or `has_one :routine`, or does it `belong_to :routine`? It's not clear from what you wrote above. When you describe your models, you should describe the associations (`have_many`, `have_one`, `belongs_to` etc.) Saying a model has an "array" is not really correct, it is an association not an array.

Comment: Posted an update, but I'm still not sure it will work. I think at this point you'd better try figuring this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Add to as_json method with the additional method-attributes you desire to the class in which you are calling.

```
class MainTemplate
  ...

  def name
    User.find(self.user_id).name
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    options[:methods] = :name
    super(options)
  end

end
```